# How to decrease value by designed order. For loop seems to break in the middle

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to make a function that decreases values of an array by specific order.
the values should be decreased by order noodle -> bread -> rice.

I tried to make the function below.

But it does not work well.

the loop break before achiving array_sum($stapleArray) ===$sizeDayArray.

$stapleArray
should be deducted until the total size equals $sizeDayArray

E.g.

input

```
targetWeekDayArrayArray
(
[0] => tue
[1] => wed
[2] => fri
[3] => sat
)
*size = 4

$sizeDayArray = size_of($targetWeekDayArrayArray)
$stapleArray=
Array
(
[rice] => 5
[bread] => 0
[noodle] => 1
)
```

expected result

```
$stapleArray=
Array
(
[rice] => 4
[bread] => 0
[noodle] => 0
)
```

caller

```
        $differenceSettingAndDay =  array_sum($stapleArray)- sizeof($targetWeekDayArray);

        $size = sizeof($targetWeekDayArray);
        $stapleArray= $this->substractStapleFood($differenceSettingAndDay,$stapleArray, $size);
```

```
    private function substractStapleFood($substractionnumber,$stapleArray,$sizeDayArray)
    {
        $array_key = ['noodle','bread','rice'];


        for($i = 0; array_sum($stapleArray) ===$sizeDayArray ; $i++ )
        {
            $i_mod = $i % count($stapleArray); //$i % 3
            $key = $array_key[$i_mod];
            if (isset($stapleArray[$key]) && $stapleArray[$key] > 0) {
                $stapleArray[$key]--;
            }


        }

        return $stapleArray;
    }
```

Actual result

```
Array
(
[rice] => 5
[bread] => 0
[noodle] => 1
)
```

It seems that id did not go through the loop.

Comment: You realise that `array_sum($stapleArray) === $sizeDayArray` evaluates to boolean which is probably what you don't want in loop definition as second expression? [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong in line :

```
for($i = 0; array_sum($stapleArray) ===$sizeDayArray ; $i++ )
```

condition `array_sum($stapleArray) ===$sizeDayArray` start is false => loop is not running

Change same as :

```
for($i = 0; !(array_sum($stapleArray) ===$sizeDayArray) ; $i++ )
```